# Integrating OpenTok and Google Calendar

Tags: php, drupal-7, google-calendar-api, opentok, tokbox

I would like to create OpenTok Sessions and Tokens which are based on events in a Google Calendar and I was wondering if anyone has tried to do the same thing and had any luck with it?

I would like to create a unique Session for each calendar event and then create a number of Tokens which have a lifespan equal to the event length. A single admin user would synchronize this calendar with their iPad calendar and add and edit events from that interface. A back end PHP system would then have to listen for new events and event changes and react appropriately.

Is this possible? Would anybody who has dealt with something similar recommend this approach or would you suggest a different route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is surely possible. I'd recommend instead of storing a number of tokens, to actually generate them on the fly when someone joins the event, there's no network call to make them so this is actually pretty inexpensive.

You may also want to check out the new [Cloud Raptor SDK](http://labs.opentok.com/raptor/index.php) we just announced to listen for interesting events. Its only available in Java right now, not PHP, but eventually we will have more languages supported.

Comment: We have since got this under way and Tokens are generated on the fly, all the same good answer for anybody else looking.